# How to modify CSS in order to have the payment form with black background?

Tags: css, braintree

i have a design question, i am a backend developer, so usually i dont do much CSS, so please be detailed with the answer, but i think the question is simple:

How i can modify the CSS in order to have the Drop-in UI (payment form) with black background and white font?

JS code is:

```
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "dropin",
  paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
  // code
}});
```

CSS code is:

```
<script type="text/braintree-css">
button.link {
outline: 0;
color: #beb79a;
text-decoration: none;
}
.no-touch button.link:hover {
color: #986d3d;
}
.modal-wrap {
font-family: 'Trajan Pro', serif;
background: #000;
color: #ffffff;
}
.no-touch .list-payment-methods-view .payment-methods-list .payment-method-item:hover {
background-color: #222222;
}
.payment-method-item .payment-method-type {
color: #ffffff;
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Show us what have you got so far, we cannot help you without some code and a more precise explanation!

Comment: The background of the page is black, and the background of the drop-in UI is white. So i want the background of the drop-in UI to be black also.

Comment: @NicolasMelendez You really need to provide way more context. How can we know what the drop-in UI is? What's the HTML code for that?

Comment: @bart ok, i add the js code, but is pretty simple, it does all with the defaults.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this without the html. But guessing by the CSS, change the color in .payment-method-item to #000

Comment: Surely as a back-end developer you must understand the annoyance of unclear assignments, either by clients, by peers, or by management. By anyone, really.

Comment: @NicolasMelendez Please add the HTML code. This is still a guessing game.

Comment: I see everyone coming down on you while your question makes perfect sense for me, in my opinion, you simply forgot to set the context of your question which is Braintree drop in UI. That being said, it's not possible to customize the braintree drop in UI because it's loaded in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, here's what I learned:

It's not possible to edit the contents of the iframe (the Braintree element that is added to the page). You can explore this for yourself by adding an onReady callback and interacting with the $("#braintree-dropin-frame") element.

My workaround was to use  wrappers with borders, to provide some way of styling how the dropin displays on the page. It's not possible to change the color without using a [custom integration](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/drop-in).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, next time I'll create a new question. I've edited my answer to remove the question-ey parts.